# In React Native, should accessibilityLabel be localized?

Tags: react-native, localization, accessibility

I assume that the accessibilityLabel for a component should be localized when you have an app supporting multiple languages.  Can someone confirm this is the case?  Or is there some other way you're meant to handle localization for this?

I've seen the accessibilityLanguage prop, but I have to assume that isn't actually going to do the translation for you.  I haven't been able to find anyone talking about using translations in the label itself, so I just want to confirm.

Comment: OF course that all labels have to be translated. All text in any way or another visible by the user has to be translated. For your other question I don't know at all, that's why I didn't post a real answer.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73163108/should-aria-attributes-also-be-translated-if-the-page-is-using-translations

Comment: I believe [Apple’s `accessibilityLanguage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615192-accessibilitylanguage) attribute is similar to [HTML’s `lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang): it serves to indicate language changes within a view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should aria attributes also be translated if the page is using translations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73163108/should-aria-attributes-also-be-translated-if-the-page-is-using-translations)